# javascript / jquery - getting a callback for the scroller position

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, scroll

I'm trying to get the vertical position of the browser scroll bar with javascript. I am currently using the jquery scroll() function, but I feel like the callbacks are a bit slow, and I'm wondering if there is a faster, native way to use a callback when a user scrolls in the browser. Does anyone know?

Comment: It highly depends on what the callback does. If it's executing heavy stuff, you may just want to throttle the callback so that it's only called once a second at most, for example.

Comment: thanks - do you have an example of how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you feel the callback is taking too much time to run, you could throttle it. Just keep track of the time it was last called: http://jsfiddle.net/fjjAw/.

```
var lastCalled = 0;
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  var now = Date.now();
  if(now - lastCalled > 1000) {  // only proceed if it has been one second since last call
    lastCalled = now;
    // do things
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the browser DOM level event to listen to. I recommend using jQuery since it will use this same native event and takes the pain out of crass platform / cross browser issues that can sometimes arise.

```
window.addEventListener ("scroll", function(){console.log('scrolling');});
```